# Django Allauth mails stop working when I change my smtp provider (mandrill)

Tags: python, django, email, mandrill, django-allauth

I started my app with a gmail account, and have recently upgraded to Mandrill. I am not using the API, just changed my smtp settings through env variables.

When I add the new mandrill smtp provider, my in-app mails work perfectly, but allauth's mails do not work at all. (I can see they are not rejected or bounced through mandrill's data, they're just not sent).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL to my settings.py file. I don't understand why it works with a gmail address and not a custom one, but this fixed it.